# Create first Element of List in List - Flutter, Dart

Tags: list, class, flutter, dart

I have a list inside in a list, both custom lists

*class Pricelist*

```
class Pricelist{
      String example;
      List<Categories> categoriesList = []


      Pricelist({this.example, this.categoriesList})


}
```

*class Categories*

```
class Categories{
      String name;

      Categories({this.name})
}
```

Adding a new pricelist is very simple, but for adding a new categoriesList i created this mathod inside the class Pricelist

```
addCategoryWithParameters(String givenCategoryName) {

        categoriesList.add(Categories(name: givenCategoryName));
}
```

Calling this method is actually pretty simple with just `Pricelist[i].addCategoryWithParameters("Whatever i want")`

Til here in fact everything works just fine.

**My Problem is** to add a new categoriesList when the list is empty.

*I have tried it with a categoriesList with already elements inside and it always worked well, but with an empty list it´s just returning an error*

> *What else could i use for adding the first element to a list inside a list instead of* `add()`

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is you need to initialize and manage single object data in the same class it will remove lots of confusion. **initialize Pricelist with blank categoriesList**. and add Categories using method inside Pricelist addCategories.

```
void main() {
 List<Pricelist> pList = [];
 pList.add(Pricelist(example: 'Example',categoriesList: [])); //initialize 
 Pricelist[0] with empty categoriesList
 print(pList[0].categoriesList.toString());
 pList[0].addCategories('My new cat'); //add categoriesList in Pricelist[0]
 print(pList[0].categoriesList.toString());
}

class Pricelist{
  String example;
  List<Categories> categoriesList = [];
  Pricelist({this.example, this.categoriesList});


  void addCategories(String _categories){
    categoriesList.add(Categories(name:_categories));
  }
}

class Categories{
  String name;
  Categories({this.name});
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Categories> categoriesList = {Categories(name: 'some Name')};
```

I hope this can help :)